# WPF: Kill Windows GUI (explorer.exe) and then restore it

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-interface, explorer

What I want to do is to kill the explorer.exe main process (which will result in killing the Windows gui programatically and then open the gui again. I can achieve that by manually killing and then starting the process through taskmanager, but I can't figure out how to do kill the main explorer process from a wpf visual C# program. Also, I tried killing it from taskmanager and then starting the windows gui again by:

```
var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "explorer.exe",
                    Arguments = "",
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
```

but it only starts a new explorer window, not the windows gui. Can someone help me to kill the win gui and start it again with some code, please?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's somewhat user-hostile, and I wouldn't be happy using an app that did this. BTW what do you mean by "windows gui" - open explorer windows? The taskbar?

Comment: Users of Windows from time to time could have reason to programatically "kill windows gui", was happening all the time with bug-rich games. I never thought to automatize it for myself, pitty.

Comment: @stuartd this app's main aim is to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find out the solution: killing the explorer.exe by getting the process and using Kill() only restarted the gui. To completely shut it down, use

```
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "taskkill.exe",
                Arguments = "/F /IM explorer.exe",
                UseShellExecute = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get processes by name using:

```
var explorerProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
```

Then you can loop through and kill them all:

```
foreach(var process in explorerProcesses)
{
    process.Kill()
}
```

Your program may need to be running as Administrator to kill explorer, I'm not certain.

Comment: You were right the first time, you use the process friendly name which is `explorer`, not `explorer.exe`: `var explorerProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");`

Comment: woops, my bad, sorry!

Comment: Thanks! But how about restoring the GUI? Starting explorer.exe with the code I gave in the first post only opens Windows explorer and the GUI (taskbar) still doesn't show up...

Comment: But now I see that it only restarts the gui. But I've found a solution to this already... thanks anyway